# aasm after callback with argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, aasm, acts-as-state-machine

I'm using the [aasm](https://github.com/aasm/aasm) (formerly `acts_as_state_machine`) gem in my rails 4 application. I have something like this on my `Post` model

```
  ...
  aasm column: :state do
    state :pending_approval, initial: true
    state :active
    state :pending_removal

    event :accept_approval, :after => Proc.new { |user| binding.pry } do
      transitions from: :pending_approval, to: :active
    end
  end
  ...
```

When I call `@post.accept_approval!(:active, current_user)` and the after callback gets triggered, in my console I can inspect what `user` is (that was passed into the Proc) and it's `nil`!

What's going on here? What is the correct way to call this transition?

Comment: why did you choose an abandoned gem? By the way transitions have no arguments generally

Comment: The gem was just updated yesterday so I'm not sure what you mean. Also, their README indicates that this is possible

Comment: was on another version, seems like a popular name

Comment: AASM is not abandoned.

Comment: @KyleDecot This seems to be a bug, as it is supposed to work. Could you please open an issue on https://github.com/aasm/aasm/issues?page=1&state=open ? I'll take care of that today.

Comment: @apneadiving Why do you think, the gem has been abandoned?

Answer (score 6):

Look aasm docs in section callbacks.

```
...
  aasm column: :state do
    state :pending_approval, initial: true
    state :active
    state :pending_removal

    after_all_transition :log_all_events

    event :accept_approval, after: :log_approval do
      transitions from: :pending_approval, to: :active
    end
  end
  ...
  del log_all_events(user)
    logger.debug "aasm #{aasm.current_event} from #{user}"
  end

  def log_approval(user)
    logger.debug "aasm log_aproove from #{user}"
  end
```

You can call events with needed params:

```
  @post.accept_approval! current_user
```

Answer (score 3):

It works in the current version (4.3.0):

```
event :finish do
  before do |user|
    # do something with user
  end

  transitions from: :active, to: :finished
end
```

Comment: Do you call this with `post.finish(user)`?

Answer (score 1):

```
event :accept_approval do
  transitions from: :pending_approval, to: :active
end
```

`post.accept_approval!{post.set_approvaler(current_user)}`

block to bang method will be call after transition success, if any activerecord operation, it will be wrap into transition transaction,
your can require a lock to prevent concurrency problem with option
`requires_lock: true`.

Answer (score 1):

Move `:after` to the `transitions` sections, such that:

```rb
event :accept_approval do
  transitions from: :pending_approval, 
    to: :active,
    :after => Proc.new { |user| binding.pry }
end
```

Then call it as `@post.accept_approval!(current_user)`